# How to use the DMA-DREQ/PANIC threshold of the hardware-PWM

Tags: hardware, serial, pwm, peripherals

I'm using the hardware PWM that is described on [page 138 of the BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals document](https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf).

The description of the `DMAC`-register (page 145) indicates that one can set the FIFO-threshold at which the `DREQ` or `PANIC`-signal is sent to the Direct Memory Access hardware.

Bits 7:0 specify the DMA Threshold for the `DREQ` signal and bits 15:8 the DMA Threshold for the `PANIC` signal, so there are 8 bits for each threshold. The default value is `0x7`, but there is no description on what this value actually means:

`0x7` could indicate 7 free spaces or 7 filled spaces. The FIFO has a size of 8 32bit words, so it also could be the bitmask `0b0000 0111` and indicate either 3 free spaces or 3 filled spaces.

How to use this register so the signals are sent at the proper fifo thresholds?

For reference:

1. [This bcm2835-analog-audio driver kernel patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9619247/) uses

   `writel(0x80000E0E, chip->base + PWM_REG_DMAC);`

   so it sets both thresholds to `0x0E`.
2. [This Raspberry-Pi-DMA-Example](https://github.com/Wallacoloo/Raspberry-Pi-DMA-Example) sets both thresholds to `0x01` ([`PWM_FIFO_SIZE`](https://github.com/Wallacoloo/Raspberry-Pi-DMA-Example/blob/master/dma-gpio.c#L145)) with the [comment](https://github.com/Wallacoloo/Raspberry-Pi-DMA-Example/blob/master/dma-gpio.c#L732):

   > DREQ is activated at queue < PWM_FIFO_SIZE
3. [This "PiFM"-Implementation](https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits/blob/master/PiFmDma/PiFmDma.c) uses `0xF` for both thresholds with the [comment](https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits/blob/master/PiFmDma/PiFmDma.c#L135-L137):

   > I think this means it requests as soon as there is one free slot in the FIFO  which is what we want as burst DMA would mess up our timing..
4. [This other "Raspberry PI FM Transmitter"](http://www.icrobotics.co.uk/wiki/index.php/Turning_the_Raspberry_Pi_Into_an_FM_Transmitter) just keeps the default `0x07` for both thresholds.

Has someone real knowledge about this or an idea for an experiment one could do to find out what it actually means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did setup a DMA-Chain with a PWM (running at 19.2Mhz/1920=10000Hz in serial mode) and tried different values for the thresholds and monitored the `TXFR_LEN`.

Result:

- A threshold of `1` to `10` resulted in a lot of small writes into the Fifo
- A threshold of `11` to `15` resulted in big writes.

So i assume that `1` is indeed the value for "Fill into Fifo as soon as there is a little bit of space" and `15` will wait until the Fifo is almost empty.

I couldn't determine any "in-between" values, though, but i now know, that i want to set the threshold for the PANIC-signal higher than the threshold for the normal DREQ-signal.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.